# Deleting of rows in UITableView takes too much time

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm writing a program which have array of 40k (40000) items, and present it in UITableView, after search table should filter and present only search results.

The problem is that deleting of many rows at once (for example 30000+) takes about 10 - 20 seconds and sure it's not possible to use. Can you suggest any decision of this problem?

(`tableview.reloadData()` not suited)

```
var allProducts = [Product]()
@IBOutlet weak var searchTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: UITextField?

var searchResults = [Product]()

enum Action{
    case Insert
    case Ignore
    case Remove
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchTextField?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.textFieldDidChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    DBBrain().getAllAlcProducts() { [weak self] products in
        self?.allProducts = products
    }
}

func textFieldDidChanged(_ sender: UITextField){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
        let text = sender.text!.lowercased()
        let res = self!.allProducts.filter({ $0.name.lowercased().contains(text) })
        if self?.searchTextField?.text != nil && text == self!.searchTextField!.text!{
            if let values = self?.getIndexes(forResults: res){
                self?.searchResults = res
                self?.updateTable(action: values.0, indexes: values.1)
            }
        }
    }
}

private func getIndexes(forResults products: [Product]) -> (Action, [IndexPath]){
    var indexes = [IndexPath]()
    var action = Action.Ignore
    if searchResults.count > products.count{
        var newCounter = 0
        for x in 0..<searchResults.count {
            if products.isEmpty || searchResults[x].id != products[newCounter].id {
                indexes.append(IndexPath(row: x, section: 0))
            }else {
                if newCounter < products.count - 1{
                    newCounter += 1
                }
            }
        }
        action = Action.Remove
    }else if searchResults.count < products.count{
        var oldCounter = 0
        for x in 0..<products.count {
            if searchResults.isEmpty || searchResults[oldCounter].id != products[x].id {
                indexes.append(IndexPath(row: x, section: 0))
            }else {
                if oldCounter < searchResults.count - 1 {
                    oldCounter += 1
                }
            }
        }
        action = Action.Insert
    }
    return (action, indexes)
}

private func updateTable(action: Action, indexes: [IndexPath]) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        if action != .Ignore {
            if action == .Remove {
                self?.searchTableView.beginUpdates()
                self?.searchTableView.deleteRows(at: indexes, with: .fade)
                self?.searchTableView.endUpdates()
            }else if action == .Insert {
                self?.searchTableView.beginUpdates()
                self?.searchTableView.insertRows(at: indexes, with: .fade)
                self?.searchTableView.endUpdates()
            }
        }
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searchResults.count
}
```

Comment: Does your app freeze for these 10-20 seconds? If so, you should make sure that the deletes are performed asynchronously.

Comment: Why would you be deleting 30000 rows at once? You need to update your question with a lot more relevant information about what you are doing.

Comment: Perhaps you could read up on the "infinite list" technique. It might give you an understanding how you can handle a large number of elements for a UITableView (or any list for that matter). Consider what is inscreen only and the things that would be inscreen after the change.

Comment: Presenting 40000 items to the user in a tableView is a bad idea. Even after deleting 30000+ items, no user wants to scroll through the remaining 10000. Give serious consideration to restructuring your data model and presenting the data in a more structured way that is useful and useable.

Comment: @Matt Le Fleur yes, it's freezing. Sorting of list(data source) takes less then 1 second and goes async, but exactly updating of UI takes all time and i can't perform it in background

Comment: Why is `tableview.reloadData()` not suited?

Comment: @Matt Le Fleur, It's too fast and not friendly) i can't understand why update of UI takes so much time, is it's only "redrawing" visible elements?

Comment: Too fast? I'm guessing you meant too slow :) Whilst the tableview does only displays the rows that are visible, `reloadData`, as inferred by its name, reloads all of the data for the table, so I guess that's why you don't want to use it, which is understandable with such a large number of rows.

Comment: @Matt Le Fleur, I mean too unpredictable for user. Just in one second you have table, boom, and u dont have anything.. i want use animation for fading it, but can't optimize it.

Comment: Ah ok, potentially a problem with trying to animate that many rows at the same time

Comment: Maybe you only animate the current visible cells and not the entire thing.  Still, I'd reconsider reloadData().  If you look at the vast majority of stock Apple apps, they are not animating search result changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never have a table with 30k+ cells. That's a ridiculous usage of memory. You should set a max limit to the number of cells in your rowsForSection delegate method.

Get the count of your results, and if the count is greater than 30 or so (even that is a large number), set it to 30.

It may very well be having a super huge array, too. That's a lot of memory usage, even if you aren't making cells for those.

Comment: Yes, thank you and to all others, i think i will try redesign algorithm to present less cells, and post it here.. may be it would be useful for anybody)